# How to read files with similar numbers of their names?

Tags: r

I have several text files in a directory called `mydata`

I can list them like this:

```
  dir1<- list.files ("C:\\mydata", "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```

First part of the files are named   `bg16.txt` `bg3.txt …..`bg(number).txt`.

Second part of the files are named   `yt16.txt yt3.txt …..`yt(number).txt`.

The rest of the files are named   `zj16.txt` `zj3.txt` …..`zj(number).txt`.

Random numbers but max is `20` and min is `1`.

I can read files with number `6` and apply regression:

```
b=read.table("C:\\mydata\\bg6.txt",sep=""):
         > head(b)
                x
           1 0.29
           2 0.21
z=read.table("C:\\mydata\\zj6.txt",sep=""):
        > head(z)
               x
           1 0.10
           2 0.56
y=read.table("C:\\mydata\\yt6.txt",sep=""):
        > head(y)
              x
          1 0.56
          2 0.32
 names(b)="b";names(y)="y";names(z)="z"
 dt=cbind(b,y,z)
 res6=lm(y~ b + z, data=dt)
```

Now I can do this for all files one by one manually but this will take lots of time. I wonder if there is any function to match the files that corresponds in numbers   : greb those three files in same number  `bg(number).txt, zj(number).txt, yt(number).txt`

read `yt(number).txt` as `y` and   `zj(number).txt` as `z` and `bg(number).txt` as `b` and then find regression as done for `6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the names of the files to extract the letter part and the number part. Then you could loop over the unique numbers to get the sets of files for each analysis. Something like this

```
# test data
dir1<-c("zj6.txt","yt6.txt","bg6.txt")

# Using this helper function... https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321
nn<-do.call(rbind, regcapturedmatches(dir1,regexpr("(\\w+)(\\d+)\\.txt", dir1, perl=T)))

lapply(unique(nn[,2]), function(n) {
    b <- read.table(dir1[nn[,1]=="bg" & nn[,2]==n],sep="", col.names="b");  
    z <- read.table(dir1[nn[,1]=="zj" & nn[,2]==n],sep="", col.names="z");  
    y <- read.table(dir1[nn[,1]=="yt" & nn[,2]==n],sep="", col.names="y");
    lm(y~ b + z, data=cbind(b,z,y))
})
```

Comment: Try `\\D` rather than `\\w` and try will be returned in the order that they are returned by unique()

Comment: I think if you search this site you are likely to find an answer to that question. It's a bit unrelated to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the correct pattern. For example it seems that your files are not numbered like `...001 , ...002`, so this should work to grab all the files ending in 6.

```
list.files('C:\\mydata', pattern = '[^[:digit:]]6.txt', full.names = T)
```

In your case, you only want have three different cases so you could write

```
list.files('C:\\mydata', pattern = '((bg)|(zj)|(yt))6.txt', full.names = T)
```

Now you can iterate over it, creating in every step the required patter, for example:

```
sprintf('((bg)|(zj)|(yt))%i.txt', k)
```